# How can I make a base class method access one of its derived class's shadowed properties?

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

Given this example:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 'WheelValue' here.")
    Dim car as New Car()
    car.DoSomething()

    Console.WriteLine("Expect 'FordWheelValue' here.")
    Dim ford as New Ford()
    ford.DoSomething()
End Sub

Public Class Car
    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Console.WriteLine("Car.DoSomething()")
        Console.WriteLine("Wheel=" + Wheel.Value)
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub
    Public Property Wheel As New Wheel()
End Class

Public Class Ford
    Inherits Car
    Public Shadows Property Wheel As New FordWheel()        
End Class

Public Class Wheel
    Public Value As String = "WheelValue"
End Class

Public Class FordWheel
    Public Value As String = "FordWheelValue"
End Class
End Module
```

Calls to `Ford.DoSomething()` use the base class's property `Wheel.Value`. In the interest of not duplicating code, is there a way using VB to write this cleanly so that these calls to `Ford.DoSomething()` instead grab the instance of Ford's property `FordWheel.Value`?
It seems like what I might need is a language feature like "Shadows Overrides" - but this isn't supported in VB from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the base class property overridable:

```
Public Class Car
    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Console.WriteLine("Car.DoSomething()")
        Console.WriteLine("Wheel=" + Wheel.Value)
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub
    Public Overridable Property Wheel As New Wheel()
End Class
```

Then when you declare a derived class, mark your property as "taking over" the existing one:

```
Public Class Ford
    Inherits Car
    Public Overrides Property Wheel As Wheel = New FordWheel()
End Class
```

**Note:** For this to work, you need to change your `FordWheel` type to inherit from `Wheel` type. You also just need to set the value of the fordwheel instead of creating a "shadowed" which is what would happen if you just inherited directly:

```
Public Class FordWheel
    Inherits Wheel

    Public Sub New()
        Value = "FordWheel"
    End Sub

End Class
```

And as Saragis said, you should just set the `Wheel` property to `New FordWheel` directly in the constructor of `Ford`, just like I did above with `FordWheel`

Comment: This won't work, FordWheel cannot be the return type instead of Wheel since they differ in types.

Comment: I think the only option is really to refactor and introduce an interface.

Comment: You're right. I didn't see that he structured his code that way... It's not clear what he wants to do exactly, according to the title question though, he needs to use `Overridable` and `Overrides` keywords.

Comment: One of the key things that makes this not work is that you cannot override to a different return type.

Comment: Also, changing Ford's property to type 'Wheel' the ford.doSomething() will still hit FordWheel. Also attempted Ford's property as Wheel As Wheel = New FordWheel()

Comment: It does work. I just tried and it and it compiles fine. You have to change FordWheel to inherit from Wheel. And do what you said `As Wheel = New FordWheel()`

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the type of Wheel you are using inside the Ford class. Wheel doesn't need to be defined in Ford anymore, since the signature would be the same. FordWheel is now a descendant of Wheel and overrides the Value property.

```
Public Class Car

    Public Sub New()
        Wheel = New Wheel()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Console.WriteLine("Car.DoSomething()")
        Console.WriteLine("Wheel=" + Wheel.Value)
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub

    Public Property Wheel As Wheel
End Class

Public Class Ford
    Inherits Car

    Public Sub New()
        Wheel = New FordWheel()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Wheel
    Public Overridable Property Value As String = "WheelValue"
End Class

Public Class FordWheel
    Inherits Wheel

    Public Overrides Property Value As String = "FordWheelValue"
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

As both of those who have answered points out , you need to make use of the oop concept of Generalization as `FordWheel` is a `Wheel`.
And the Following code is just the resemblance of a popular design pattern called Bridge Pattern where implementations and concretions are separated out.

Public Class Car

```
Public Sub New()
    Wheel = New Wheel()
End Sub

Public Property Wheel As Wheel
End Class

Public Class Ford
     Inherits Car

    Public Sub New()
        Wheel = New FordWheel()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Wheel
    Public Overridable Property Value As String = "WheelValue"
End Class

Public Class FordWheel
    Inherits Wheel

    Public Overrides Property Value As String = "FordWheelValue"
End Class

Public Class Executor
   Public Sub Main()
      Console.WriteLine("Expect 'WheelValue' here.")
      Dim car as New Car()
      Console.WriteLine(car.Wheel)

      Console.WriteLine("Expect 'FordWheelValue' here.")
      Dim ford as New Ford()
      Console.WriteLine(ford.Wheel)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Sorry for wrong syntax if any , As i'm a Java Developer.